# HTML Zoom Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

```js
console.clear();

function first_image() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;"><svg id="svg-id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1"><path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/></svg></div>';
  first_image_scroll()

  function first_image_scroll() {

    $(function() {
      panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-id', {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: false,
        zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.7,
        minZoom: 0.005
      });
      //panZoomInstance.zoom(1.1);  
    })

  }

}

first_image()

function second_image() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;"><svg id="svg-id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1"><path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 "/></svg></div>';
  second_image_scroll()

  function second_image_scroll() {

    $(function() {
      panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-id', {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: false,
        zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.7,
        minZoom: 0.005
      });
      //panZoomInstance.zoom(1.1);  
    })

  }

}

second_image()
```

```css
.main-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-pan-zoom@3.5.0/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>


<div>
  <button onclick="first_image()">First Image</button>
  <button onclick="second_image()">Second Image</button>
</div>
```

Library Documentation : [github here](https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom);

I have created a very interactive zooming in and out with Pan Functionality on SVG image, and my codepen demo at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/qBMVgbN. You can click and drag to pan or use the ball of your mouse to zoom in and out. There are 2 buttons which are first image and second image which the first image is a letter 2 and the second is a cut-off letter 2.  You can try to put the letter 2 on the top left hand side corner as shown in my images,  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHIHE.png)  and  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4YtE.png) and after that you can try to press the 2 buttons to swap the images  and you will see that the number 2 and the half 2 keeps centering itself which is not the effect I want.

My goal is to be able to **swap the images and also keep the position fixed for both images**, like when you drag a number 2 to the top left corner, and when you click on the other image which is a half 2, the half 2 image will also be at **the same position** as the the number 2 previously.

I have tried to remove the centering of the zoom functionality but it does not work, sadly :)
 `zoomEnabled: true, controlIconsEnabled: false, zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.7, minZoom: 0.005`

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform.

Comment: @CBroe, hi sir, I have really tried to simplified it, this is the most simplified code :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this :) ?

Comment: Well I guess you would have to _get_ the current zoom parameters, before you switch away from the current image, and then apply those again, when you show it again.

Comment: @CBroe, yes , that will work, but what about positioning? haha :)

Comment: @CBroe, basically the functionality I wish to create is like, you know, if you ever used Autocad for drawing, you can just click on the lines and delete the lines without the entire screen zooming or moving away ? It must stay in position :)

Comment: "Position" is actually the "pan" then with this library, I suppose? Well according to the docs, it has methods to get and set that ...

Comment: Don't re-create the image when switching it, just hide it, and do changes to both of the images when panning/zooming.

Comment: @Teemu, hi, I am unsure how to implement that :), can you show some examples :) ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the used library, you've to read the docs. As CBroe said, "_it has methods to get and set [position and zoom]_".

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for the help anyways, I have also attached the library documentation in my post.

Comment: @Yogi, hello, thanks for replying :), can you show some examples on how to implement this :) ?